# Algebraic ode of exponential generating series

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, mp.mathematical-physics, algebraic-combinatorics, kac-moody-algebras

Let $G(z)$ be a rational function. So if we have a series
$$S(x):=\sum_{n}a_n x^n  $$ where
$$ a_n = \prod_{i=1}^{n}G((i-1)h) $$
We can conclude that the series satisfies a Linear differential equation with polynomial coefficients as the ratio of the $a_{n+1}/a_n $ is rational.
Now we have a series of the form
$$Sexp(x):=\sum_{n}b_n x^n  \tag{*}$$ where
$$ b_n = \exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}G((i-1)h) \right)$$ can we conclude that there exist a change of coordinate say $X(x)$ such that it will also satisfy linear differential equation with polynomial coefficient? So what would be that change of coordinate?
Let me give me an example and ask if we can change the operator so that it would be linear ode in that particular operator?
$$
Z(x,h) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n! h^i}\exp(n^2-n)
$$
Now if we take the ratio of $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}= \frac{x\exp(n)}{(n+1)} $
Hence the operator
$$ 
hx\partial_x - (x \exp(hx\partial_x))
$$
Let define $A_x = \exp(hx\partial_x)$

Hence we get a differential equation in terms of $\partial_x, A_x$ that annihilate our function $Z(x,h)$.
My question is
Is it possible to get a Algebraic ode in terms of $\partial_x , A_x$ such for my series $S\exp(x)$

Comment: You have a trouble with indices in the sum for $Z(x,h)$

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected it.